# Deploy features.xml in servicemix during jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-3, apache-servicemix, maven-deploy-plugin

I have my features.xml file in src/main/resources/features folder , when I build my project through Jenkins after building my bundle goes to the nexus repository , my requirement is that after my bundle goes to nexus then features.xml should automatically be deployed on servicemix as part of build only. I should not open the servicemix console to install the feature. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You may think about using a KAR (KAraf aRchive). 
More information can be found here: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/users-guide/kar.html

You can build а KAR (through Jenkins), containing your feature, then you can use a hot deployment.

> Apache Karaf also provides a KAR deployer. It means that you can drop
>   a KAR file directly in the deploy folder.
>
> Apache Karaf will automatically install KAR files from the deploy
>   folder. You can change the behaviours of the KAR deployer in the
>   etc/org.apache.karaf.kar.cfg:

Answer (score 0):

I have also been working on this and my solution was to turn to automated scripting to accomplish this.  I wrote a ssh and FTP based program which would stop an smx, delete the ${karaf.home}/data/cache/ directory, replace the new feature file with the one retrieved from the ftp operation, then restart the karaf container.

If you are open to looking into other possibilities:

You can look into Fuse Fabric which can link many smx Containers together and implement version increases and rollbacks.  Currently I believe this would also need scripting to accomplish it automatically.

The third option is relatively new and comes in the form of Building docker images and deploying them via OpenShiftV3 which was just unveiled at the Redhat Summit 2015.  Its worth noting its fairly new, but it does pack a very impressive feature set.